# what functions to use to resize images and create DB metadata for them after/during upload?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, images, uploads

I am working on my first script to create a WP post with images and upload those images to the uploads folder.

I am clear about `wp_insert_post` and was able to upload an image to the server with `wp_handle_upload`, but what do I do after it's uploaded to create all its resized versions (for responsive design) and add all the relevant metadata info to the database?

Also do I need `wp_media_upload_handler` (since it takes no parameters) and, if so, how/when do I run that in relation to wp_handle_upload?

Comment: Try [`media_handle_upload()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/) which automatically creates the resized versions.

Comment: thank you @SallyCJ - is it automatic or do I have to tell it what sizes to create? and will this function also create database metadata and other relevant database entries?

Comment: It uses the image sizes registered via [`add_image_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) including standard sizes such as thumbnail and 'medium' - see the Media Settings admin screen. And yes, the function does create the metadata; see `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()` and `wp_update_attachment_metadata()` in the "Uses" section [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/#uses).